# Relationship among split view controller, tab bar controller, and multiple tableview controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

In my universal app with a split view controller at the top of the hierarchy, I want a tab bar controller with multiple table view controllers as the tabs. What should the storyboard and relationships look like?

I started with the default empty universal master/detail project. I got the standard split view controller with two navigation controllers pointing to the master table view controller and detail view controller. If I embed that master table view controller in a tab bar controller, that table view controller's detail view (actually, the detail view's navigation controller) remains the split view controller's detail view. When I add another table view controller and make it a tab of the tab bar controller, how to I hook that table view and its detail view to the split view controller?  Whew.

Thanks!

...R

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your desired structure properly, the graphic below should illustrate the relationships you want. (Direct Link to Full-Res Image: http://cl.ly/image/0S3y3V3O0930/Screen%20Shot%202015-05-21%20at%202.28.29%20PM.png)

[image]

Comment: That's close, but (I think) not quite. E.g.: A company has products, employees, and stores. At the top, I have one split VC. That split VC's master should be one tab bar controller (TBC) (I think). The first tab of the TBC's tabs would be the products table VC, and that products table VC would push a product detail VC when a row is selected.  The second tab would be the employees table VC that would push an employee detail VC.  And the third tab would be the stores table VC that would push to a store detail VC.